# Why do unstable manifolds of two close point intersect each other in Baker map?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be $S^1 \times [-1,1]$, $f$ a [baker map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_map) on $M$ and for $p, q \in M$ consider $W^s_p$ the stable manifold in $p$ (i.e. the set of points whose forward orbit tend to the forward orbit of $p$) and $W^u_q$ the unstable manifold in $q$ (i.e. the set of points whose backward orbit tends to backwards orbit of $q$).
Let us assume, we have transversality.
Question:

> Let $x\in W^u_p$ and $y\in W^u_q$. Show that there exists a point $t$ so that $t\in W^u_x \cap W^u_y$, if $x$ and $y$ be small close to each other. I want to say that if two point be close to each other their unstable manifold will intersect each other at a point.
>
> Under which assumption we can prove it the intersection point is unique?

When we draw baker map we easily see they intersect a point but i do not know how can i prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not true. In fact if we assume that $f$ is Anosov then locally the stable manifolds form a decomposition, hence the only way that that $W^u_x$ and $W^u_y$ can have nonempty intersection is if they are equal. Are you sure you wrote the question correctly?

Comment: Is the result you want that (under some conditions) the *stable manifold* of $x$ meets the unstable manifold of $y$?

Comment: @LeeMosher : Thanks for your comment. I forgot to write map is Baker. When we draw picture we will see their unstable manifold intersect each other but I can not prove it

Comment: @AnthonyQuas : Thanks for your comment. No, I know when we have local product structure stable and unstable manifold intersect each other . But as I said I want to show that unstable manifolds intersect each other in Baker map. We see they intersect each other when we draw it but I do not know how I can prove it.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a definition or a link to a "Baker map". I know what **the** [Baker's map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_map) is, but presumably that is not what you mean because its stable and unstable manifolds do indeed have a local product structure.

Comment: @LeeMosher : Yes, But I asked why unstable manifold $W_{x}^{u}$ and $W_{y}^{y}$ intersect each other. And then, why it is unique?

Comment: @LeeMosher : I understood stable and unstable manifold intersect each other but I would like to know why unstable manifolds intersect each other. I will appreciate if you help me or introduce some references.

Comment: The link by Lee Mosher is for a map on the unit disc, not some arbitrary Riemannian manifold. You're asking for that specific map?

Comment: @Mike Miller. You're right. I modified the question. I'm looking for a map that defines on $ S^1 \times [-1, 1]$

Comment: If $t\in W^u(x)\cap W^u(y)$, then $d(f^{-n}t,f^{-n}x)\to 0$ and $d(f^{-n}t,f^{-n}y)\to 0$, so that $d(f^{-n}x),f^{-n}y)\to 0$. Of course this is not the case for typical nearby $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: It doesn't mean they intersect each other, does it? because maybe they are very close to each other.

Comment: I am really interested to know what is mathematic reason in nonlinear Baker, two unstable manifold intersect each other.

Comment: The point is that for most $x$ and $y$, $y$ does not lie in the unstable manifold of $x$ (otherwise the unstable manifold would be of the wrong dimension). This implies (as I showed above) that there is no $t$ lying in the intersection of the unstable manifolds.